# Using Smarty {strip} how does this affect performance?

Tags: smarty, smarty3

I have always wondered the pros/cons of using the {strip} modifier for Smarty.

Would the extra time that it takes the server to strip the empty spaces from the template, out weigh the decreased load time with smaller files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`{strip}`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.strip.tpl) is a compile-time thing. It removes all superfluous white-space including line-breaks. But it does this when compiling your template to php. So this is done exactly once. Rendering time is the same for using or not using {strip}.

If you want to remove all superfluous white-space, you're probably looking for the [trimwhitespace output-filter](http://code.google.com/p/smarty-php/source/browse/trunk/distribution/libs/plugins/outputfilter.trimwhitespace.php).